# How to iterate over json object in python containing dictionary and list

Tags: json, django, python-2.7, dictionary

```
 {'PCCandidateDetails': {'BatchId': '456279',
  'Candidate': 'Noori sahi ',
  'CandidateId': '9124657',
  'CenterName': 'K',
  'ProjectName': 'PKKVY',
  'QPName': 'Domestic Data Entry Operator(SSC/Q2212)',
  'TrainingProviderName': 'OrionEdutechPrivateLimited'},
 'PCTestScores': [{'MaxScore': 12,
   'PCId': 'SRC/N3022_PC1',
   'PCName': 'obtain sufficient information from the customer /client to understand the need and perform initial task',
   'Percentage': 0,
   'YourScore': 0},
  {'MaxScore': 15,
   'PCId': 'SRC/N3022_PC10',
   'PCName': 'compares transcribed data, as displayed on a visual screen, document and corrects any errors with the source',
   'Percentage': 0,
   'YourScore': 0},
  {'MaxScore': 5,
   'PCId': 'SSC/N3022_PC11',
   'PCName': 'obtain help or advice from specialist if the problem is outside his/her area of competence or experience',
   'Percentage': 0,
   'YourScore': 0}]}
```

> I want to loop over this json object which I have got using web request.

```
import requests,ast
r = requests.get("some url")
data = r.text
data_dic = ast.literal_eval(data)
```

> When I try to loop over the Json  I am not able to fetch the expected output in key- Value pair. I want output like this

```
BatchId : 456279 
Candidate : Noori sahi
CandidateId :9124657 ...
```

> and so on. Below code is My approach but dictionary inside the list is causing problem in looping.

```
for i in data_dic:
        for k,v in i.iteritems():
            print k,v
```

> What I'm getting as error is 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'. What is the right approach for looping this kind of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for your example (python 3.5.2) but i don't know if is the best approach (I mean, maybe there are some `json` parsing functions easier to use):

```
for v, k in itms.items():
    if not isinstance(k, list):
        for x, y in k.items():
            print(x,':', y)
    else:
        for i in k:
            for s, m in i.items():
                print(s,':', m)
```

with the result:

```
CandidateId : 9124657
BatchId : 456279
QPName : Domestic Data Entry Operator(SSC/Q2212)
CenterName : K
ProjectName : PKKVY
Candidate : Noori sahi 
TrainingProviderName : OrionEdutechPrivateLimited
Percentage : 0
PCName : obtain sufficient information from the customer /client to understand the need and perform initial task
MaxScore : 12
YourScore : 0
PCId : SRC/N3022_PC1
Percentage : 0
PCName : compares transcribed data, as displayed on a visual screen, document and corrects any errors with the source
MaxScore : 15
YourScore : 0
PCId : SRC/N3022_PC10
Percentage : 0
PCName : obtain help or advice from specialist if the problem is outside his/her area of competence or experience
MaxScore : 5
YourScore : 0
PCId : SSC/N3022_PC11
```

for python 2.7. only remove the parentheses from `print`

```
for v, k in itms.items():
    if not isinstance(k, list):
        for x, y in k.items():
            print x,':', y
    else:
        for i in k:
            for s, m in i.items():
                print s,':', m
```

Answer (score 0):

To get data use:

```
import json
data = json.loads(request.body)
print data['PCTestScores']
for values in data['PCTestScores']:
    print values
    print values['PCId']
    print values['PCName']
    print values['Percentage']
    print values['MaxScore']
    print values['YourScore']
```

Comment: I already tried it but output is same. I am having problem in only  looping as it has one dictionary and anotherone is dictionary inside the list.

Comment: can you post your code? as `dict_data`  is not in your JSON response.
Or you talking about `PCTestScores` ?

Comment: import requests,json

In [15]: r = requests.get('some url')

In [16]: data = json.loads(r.content)

In [17]: type(data)
Out[17]: dict